# Optimal way of join with counting Arango

Tags: count, arangodb, nosql

I wanted to write a most efficent query in Arango Query Language working like join with counting.

In database I have **Users**, **Tags** and **userTag** collections. **Users** and **Tags** are connected by '**edge**' stored in **userTag**.
I want to list all **Tags** (with data from Tags collection) and to each tag - **number of users connected to Tag**.

What I have (it works):

```
FOR tag in tags
    let forOneTag = (
      FOR v, e, p IN 1 OUTBOUND tag
      ANY userTag
        RETURN {e}
    )
    RETURN {tag: tag.tagname, numberOfUsers: LENGTH(forOneTag)}
```

I feel it is not the most efficient way regarding time and memory.
Is there more 'arangoic' way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is already good. One small optimisation: Use `RETURN e` instead of `RETURN {e}`, you don't have to wrap `e` inside a document because it's already a document.

```
FOR tag in tags
  let forOneTag = (
    FOR v, e, p IN 1 OUTBOUND tag
      ANY userTag
      RETURN e
    )
  RETURN {tag: tag.tagname, numberOfUsers: LENGTH(forOneTag)}
```

Alternatively you could use the following query. These query is more performant but only returns tags which has at least one connected user.

```
FOR tag in tags
  FOR v, e, p IN 1 OUTBOUND tag
    ANY userTag
    RETURN {tag: tag.tagname, numberOfUsers:LENGTH(p.edges)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the count of outbounds from `Tags` to your `Users` and have fairly limited number of relations in your `userTags` Relation collection, you can do something like this

```
FOR tag in Tags
  let usersOutBound = (
    FOR relation in userTag
      FILTER relation._from == tag._id
      return relation
  )
  return {tag: tag.tagname, numberOfUsers: LENGTH(usersOutBound)}
```